# How to apply python for loops over Kusto query?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Assume I have a list, I wants my Kusto query run for every item of the list .

(On jupyter nb)

List=[Aa,Bb,Cc,....]

%%kql

Let dt=Stormevent
Where city == “Aa”/ “Bb”....;

Dt

Comment: I don't see any way to use %%kql in a loop. You will probably need to use a Kusto client and write a script for looping.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ٪kql line magic instead of %%kql cell magic. It will allow you to embbed the query within python code.
(if the query is too long, you can assign the query string to a variable q and invoke it as follow %kql -query=q)

To query for a different city in each iteration you can parametrize the query, by setting enable_curly_brackets_params option

After each %kql invocation the current result can be found in _ so you cam assign it to your esult array.

```py
    q = """Let dt=Stormevent Where city == {city};dt"""
    result = {}
    for city in ["boston", "new york"]:
        %kql -enable_curly_brackets_params -query=q
        result[city] = _
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in a loop, e.g.:

```
for i in range(10):
    q = 'print 1 | project x=rand()'
    %kql res << -query q
    df = res.to_dataframe()
    print(i, ') ', df.loc[0, 'x'])
```

0 )  0.8004291377064829

1 )  0.21431890478779161

2 )  0.7081267763402214

3 )  0.018282853469189432

4 )  0.09503573352465022

5 )  0.3818887889250695

6 )  0.44025744193602245

7 )  0.08743012512835481

8 )  0.11206495163806265

9 )  0.39447086339688847